# Symfony Sonata Admin Bundle - export custom fields with twig templates to XLS

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony3.x

**Code**

My Sonata admin class code:

```
class UsersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
.....
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

        $listMapper
            ->add('getSummaryTimeInGame','string',[
                'label'    => 'Summary time in game',
                'template' =>'AdminBundle::get_summary_time_in_game.html.twig'
            ])
            ->add('getPercentTasksDone', 'string', [
                'label'    => 'Percents tasks done',
                'template' => 'AdminBundle::get_percent_tasks_done.html.twig'
            ])
    }

   public function getExportFields()
   {
       return [
            'Name'     => 'name',
            'Surname'  => 'surname',
            'Summary time in game' => 'getSummaryTimeInGame',
            'Percents tasks done'  => 'getPercentTasksDone',
       ];
   }

.....
}
```

**Problem**

Fields 'getSummaryTimeInGame' and 'getPercentTasksDone' are visible on datagrid list view, **but when exported to XLS, they are blank**.

How to list these fields correctly on XLS export?

Comment: Both getSummaryTimeInGame & getPercentTasksDone are existing methods on your linked entity ?

Comment: @AirBair These methods don't exists in linked entity. Custom logic for values of these fields are in twig templates (given as parameter 'template' in $listMapper)

Comment: That's why it doesn't work ! The export action is independant of the list configuration. Values in export fields must correspond to the name of an attribute or a method into the linked entity.
According to the doc : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/action_export.html

Comment: @AirBar  So, how to include custom logic value in exported fields?
I'd like to use my service in twig template to get value . Injecting service to Entity is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your user entity(entity linked to this admin class) create these two functions.

```
public function getSummaryTimeInGame{
    // return the desired calculated value.
}

public function getPercentTasksDone(){
    // return the desired calculated value.
}
```

After this export your sheet and will get these values in your file.